# React + Django Axios Issues

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I have a react application linked to a Django backend on two separate servers. I am using DRF for django and I allowed cors using django-cors-headers. For some reason when I curl POST the backend, I am able to get the request out. However when I use axios POST the backend, I get and error. The status of the POST request from axios is failed. The request and takes more than 10 seconds to complete. My code was working locally (both react and django codes), but when I deployed to AWS ec2 ubuntu, the axios requests stopped working.

Console error logs

> ```
> OPTIONS http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
> ```

```
{
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/",
    "data": "{\"username\":\"testaccount\",\"password\":\"testpassword\"}"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Here is my request code

```
axios.post('http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/',
                JSON.stringify(data),
                {
                    mode: 'no-cors',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
                    },
                 },
            ).then( res => (
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res)),

            )
            ).catch( err => (
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
                )
            );
```

my curl code that worked

```
curl -d '{"username":"testaccount", "password":"testpassword"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/
```

UPDATE 1

on firefox i am getting the warning

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/. (Reason:
>   CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

UPDATE 2

Perhaps it has something to do with my AWS VPC and subnets? My django server is in a private subnet while my react app is in a public subnet.

UPDATE 3 - my idea of what the problem is

I think the reason why my requests from axios aren't working is because the requests i'm making is setting the origin of the request header to http://18.207.204.70:3000 - the public/external ip address - instead of the private/internal ip address which is http://10.0.2.219:3000 - i search online that the origin is a forbidden field so it can't be changed. How can i set the origin then? Do I have to use a proxy - how can I do that.

Comment: Have you tried it with fetch()?, some axios functions don't translate 1:1 with xhtmlrequest as a wrapper

Comment: yes - i just tried same error except the Options header wasn't sent out first POST http://10.0.3.98:8000/token-auth/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: You need to have your application server respond to preflight `OPTIONS` requests with a response header that specifies which host origins are allowed to request to the application server. The response header that must be set back in response to a preflight request is [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: I tried that also, i'll update my question with the headers i used

Comment: oh, the application server at `http://10.0.3.98:8000/` must be updated to respond to preflights requests from the host running the script. I don't mean setting the request headers in the `axios` client.

Comment: so the thing is even if i use application/x-www-form-urlencoded which doesnt send out preflights - the calls still dont work.

Answer (score 0):

try this http request instead of **axios**, it's called superagent (https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) , just install it to your react app via npm,

```
npm i superagent
```

and use this instead of axios.

```
import request from 'superagent'

    const payload ={
                    "1": this.state.number,
                    "2": this.state.message
                    }


    request.post('LINK HERE')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .send(payload)
            .end(function(err, res){
                if (res.text==='success'){
                    this.setState({
                        msgAlert: 'Message Sent!',
                    })
                }
                else{
                    console.log('message failed/error')
                }
            });
```

Comment: Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

Comment: i think it has something to do with reactjs or my packages. when i write a node script trying with axios, fetch, or superagent - they all work. when i put the code in the react project, they no longer work.

Comment: Usually browsers make a preflight request to verify if the host in which a script is running is allowed to perform request on another host. This allows for only hosts verified by the application server to make browser requests to an application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the request is being made on the client browser. You need to either use a reverse proxy or request directly to the api server. You cannot do a local ssh forwarding either.